# Waiting for an async call to finish before passing to a new a new observable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have some difficulties with some rxjs calls and I could use some help. My problems is to parcours a list of ids, make an async call for each id and then pass on the next id once this async call is finish. Unfortunaly I did not manage to find a proper solution yet.

Here my code so far:

```
import { from, interval, of, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, filter, flatMap, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const callFinised$ = new Subject();

const makeAsyncCall = val => {
  console.log('start call for ', val);
  interval(1000)
    .pipe(take(1))
    .subscribe(() => {
      callFinised$.next(true);
      console.log('call finished for ', val);
    });
};

from(['id1', 'id2'])
  .pipe(
    concatMap(val => {
      return of(val).pipe(
        flatMap(() => {
          makeAsyncCall(val);
          return callFinised$;
        }),
        filter(callFinised => callFinised === true),
        take(1),
        map(() => {
          return val + '_updated';
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(finalVal => console.log('finalVal', finalVal));
```

Here the stackblitz associated: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-shnm6q?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100)

The second id is emited before the first async is finished, so I'm a bit lost.

Best regards

Comment: You really shouldn't use a global subject for this. Make `makeAsyncCall` return an observable itself.

Comment: Yes I should but this example is over simplified compared to my real code. In my real code the async call is buried way under inside the makeAsyncCallFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that (I think) does what you're after.

```ts
const makeAsyncCall = val => defer(() => {
  console.log('start call for ', val);
  return timer(1000).pipe(
    map(_ => true),
    tap(_ => console.log('call finished for ', val))
  );
});

from(['id1', 'id2']).pipe(
  concatMap(id => makeAsyncCall(id).pipe(
    filter(callFinished => callFinished === true),
    map(_ => id + '_updated')
  ))
).subscribe(finalVal => console.log('finalVal', finalVal));
```

#### Update:

Defer doesn't accomplish anything for you in the code above since you call `makeAsyncCall` at basically the same time you `subscribe` to the returned observable.

However, creation and subscription to Observables are different things.

In the following code, I create all the Observables first and then afterward I concatenate them and call them one after another. Without defer, this code wouldn't output what you're expecting.

```ts
const idCalls = ["id1", "id2"].map(id => 
  makeAsyncCall(id).pipe(
    filter(callFinished => callFinished === true),
    map(_ => id + '_updated')
  )
);

concat(...idCalls).subscribe(
  finalVal => console.log('finalVal', finalVal)
);
```

Comment: Thanks it works indeed. I did not know about the defer function.

Comment: @HelloWorld888 Hey, I've updated my answer with a bit more info on `defer` since when it is useful is often confusing.